# Append Whitespace to stringbuilder Left Justified

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I am using the following to append WhiteSpaces:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0,15}", "TEST");
```

But this is Right Justified.

How to make this Left Justified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0,-15}", "TEST");
```

See: [StringBuilder.AppendFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cazfhf32%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)